# MS Access Combobox Row Source Issues

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2016

Have not been able to find an answer to this issue...

This is my Value list Row Source *Homeroom;Period 2;Period 3;Period 4;Period 5;Period 6;Period 7;Advisory*

When I open the form...Only every other (starting at second value) is shown.

For example:

Period 2
Period 4
Period 6
Advisory

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...Number of Columns and width of Columns were fighting me...